# Windows 10 sshd, renaming an account does not change ssh username

Tags: windows, sshd

I have a Windows 10 Home system with 3 user accounts.  One of them, as an example, is "Dan Stromberg" (without the quotes). Windows 10's sshd was happy with this.

A Linux application I use was having problems with the space in that name, so I renamed the accounts to use dashes instead of spaces - EG Dan-Stromberg.  To do this, I used Control Panel -> User Accounts -> User Accounts -> Change Your Account Name.

But I can't ssh into the Windows 10 machine as Dan-Stromberg.  I *can* still ssh in as "Dan Stromberg" (without the quotes), despite the renaming.  This defeats the purpose of the renaming.

When I look at the Windows 10 login screen, the names appear with dashes and not spaces.  How can I persuade Windows 10 sshd to do the same?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you restart the PC after changing names?

Comment: No, I did not reboot.  I did do a "net stop sshd" and "net start sshd". I'll try a reboot when the PC is free.

Comment: Rebooting did not help.

Comment: It turned out to be easier to fix the quoting in the Linux application.  But I remain curious about how to get Windows 10 to fully rename an account.